# How to query using a collection group Firebase Security

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to query data securely using a collection group query (The owner id is stored in the documents inside of the finance collection).

My Data model looks like this:

```
usuarios > user.uid > capaigns > finance > document
```

This is my query code:

```js
  const financeQuery = query(
    collectionGroup(db, "finance"),
    where("owner", "==", match.params.uid)
  );
```

And this is my security rule:

```
match/usuarios/{user}/campaigns/{campaign}/finance/{documents}{
  allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner
}
```

But I am getting this error:

> FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Comment: Where is the owner ID stored?

Comment: in the documents inside of the finance collection

Comment: Can you please share screenshot of sample documents? Also are you sure user is logged in to your app while making this request? If there are no more sub-collections in finance, I would try changing the rule path to `/finance/{documents}` instead of using a recursive wildcard `/finance/{documents=**}`.

Comment: I have changed the rule path, and added my data model

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please also respond with @AlexMamo